# DataTables редактирование одной ячейки

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Знаю только Азы javascript и JQuery, Искал ответа на всех 64 темах в stackoverflow.

**Вкратце:** Обновляю содежимое ячеек таблицы jquery методом

```
$('[data-id="2"][data-name="name"]').html('Дима');
table.draw();
```

Все прекрасно обновляется и даже после table.draw(); строки фильтруются как надо!Когда применяются фильтры, в теле html пропадают `<tr><td></td></tr>` . Отрабатывает скрипт предположим `$('[data-id="2"][data-name="name"]').html('Дима');` Если этот DOM элемент отфильтрован DataTables, т.е. она его просто удалила из html, то изменение не применяется. Меняю значение в фильтре и появляется эта строка со старым значением. Знатоки подскажите в какие дебри DataTables надо залезть, чтобы иметь возможность *менять значение ячейки и атрибутов тоже* вне зависимости от того какие фильтры применены?

Смотрел в сторону обновления через json - но он меня не устроил - не понял как там задавать классы и data атрибуты. Еще не понял зачем передавать скажем 40х300 ячеек json(ом), когда мне нужно поменять значение только одно на стороне клиента, тем более что все данные для этого я уже передал на сторону клиента. Где то же этот первозданный DOM с `<tr></tr>` сидит, раз уж DataTables его держит в памяти после применения другого фильтра.

**Пример тестовый:**

```js
   var table = $('#table').dataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя</th>
      <th>Фамилия</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="2" data-name="name">Иван</td>
      <td data-id="2" data-name="surname">Иванов</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="5" data-name="name">Вася</td>
      <td data-id="5" data-name="surname">Сидоров</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается оказывается просто

**Пример:**

```
//внести изменения
table.cell('[data-id="2"][data-name="name"]').data('измененные данные');
//перерисовать
table.draw();
```